# Clojure - how to instrument another protocol in implementation

Tags: testing, clojure

I'm new in Clojure and after searching for it, I turning my problem to SO community.

I'm testing a protocol implementation (`deftype`) who has a reference to another protocol, so constructor is like this :

```
(deftype FooImpl [^Protocol2 protocol-2]
    (function bar [_] ... (.bar2 protocol-2))
)
```

The `...` are somes conditions too meet to call the `.bar2` function.

The thing that I'm not able to do, is to instrument (`conjure.core/instrumenting`) the call the `.bar2` to validate passed parameter (`verify-called-once-with-args`).

So problem is this:

```
(instrumenting [ns/function ;;In normal case with `defn`
                ????] ;; what to write for .bar2
   ....)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal usage or for testing/mocking you can use `reify` to implement the protocol:

```
(instrumenting [ns/function]
  (ns/function (reify Protocol2
                 (bar2 [_]
                   ; Your mock return value goes here
                   42))))
```

You can also roll your own checking by using `atom`:

```
(instrumenting [ns/function]
  (let [my-calls (atom 0)]
    (ns/function (reify Protocol2
                   (bar2 [_]
                     ; Increment the number of calls
                     (swap! my-calls inc)
                     ; Your mock return value goes here
                     42)))
    (is (= @my-calls 1))))
```

The above assumes you're using clojure.test, but any of the clojure unit testing libs can verify your atom's value.

Comment: Thanks, It's was useful!